# Why is my Bash script with grep not working?

Tags: bash, if-statement, grep

I'm trying to understand why this very simple script is not working:

```
echo "SomeText" > test
if [[ "grep 'FindMe' ./test" ]] ; then
  echo Why is this line written to screen?
fi
```

I have tried with:

`"grep 'FindMe' ./test"`

`$(grep 'FindMe' ./test)`

`` `grep 'FindMe' ./test` ``

also with a lot of grep options.

I have tried with `[]` and `[[]]` and `{}` and any combination.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact, to check the exit status, use no parentheses and no quotes:

```
if grep 'FindMe' ./test ; then
```

Using `grep -q` is common in such situations as we don't want the output of the script to be cluttered with random matches.